# Give an open cover with no finite subcover.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I am looking for an example of an open cover of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ (with the metric induced from the usual metric on $\mathbb R$) that has no finite subcover.

I'm at a loss because of the intersection with $\mathbb Q$.  I originally thought of $(-\frac 1n, 1+ \frac 1n$) for $n \in \mathbb N$ but then I think this has a finite subcover, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The title of a question is not part of the question. Please make the question self-contained.

Answer (score 5):

This cover has no finite subcover :

$$\Bbb Q \cap [0,1] = \bigcup_{n} \left( \Bbb Q \cap \left( \left[0,\ln(2)-\frac{1}{n}\right[\;\cup\; \left]\ln(2)+\frac{1}{n},1\right] \right)\right) $$

Edit : forgot to add the $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Thanks for answering!  Let me make sure I understand this, $ln(2)$ is irrational, which means $ln(2) - \frac 1n$ covers $0$, and $ln(2) + \frac 1n$ covers $1$.  It's open because of the $1/n$, and there would be no finite subcover because of the $ln(2)$?

Comment: Yes.The idea is take an increasing sequence $(r_n)_n$ and a decreasing sequence  $(s_n)_n$ of irrationals in $[0,1$], each converging to the irrational $x$. Tryss chose $x=\ln 2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1] $, which is possible as $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

Then $$\{(r_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},r_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}) \cap \mathbb Q \ : \ n \in \mathbb N\}$$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: @Rob I edited my answer. The idea is to have for a finite subcover the sum of the lengths of the intervals less than 1.

Comment: That fixes it (if you explain that $0 \not\in \Bbb{N}$ for you).