# An open cover $([0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}) \times ([0,1] / \Bbb{Q})$ has no finite subcover?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I was thinking about the correct statement

An open cover $([0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}) \times ([0,1] \setminus \Bbb{Q}) = \{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] : x \in \Bbb{Q} , y \notin \Bbb{Q}\} \subset (\Bbb{R}^2, d_{\infty})$ that doesnot have any finite subcover.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466084/give-an-open-cover-with-no-finite-subcover?rq=1) we see that $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ has no finite subcover but this is is a product of the rationals in $[0,1]$ and the irrationals.

Comment: Take Tryss's example, and product it with $\Bbb{R}$. Rather than getting a cover of open intervals, you'll get a cover of open vertical strips with no subcover.

Comment: You should use "\setminus" instead of "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are many covers of
$([0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}) \times ([0,1] / \Bbb{Q})$
that have finite subcovers, there are lots that do not.

If every cover had a finite subcover, then that space would be compact.  As compactness is preserved by continuous functions, such as the first projection, $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ 
would be compact, which of course, it isn't.